# Slider above the x axis in a chart?

Tags: javafx, charts, binding

I am trying to implement a `Slider` that has an `XYChart` below and is supposed to slider along the values of the x-axis. New values for the y-axis are to be dynamilcally added, so the chart may grow vertically. That's why I decided, it has to be inside a `ScrollPane`. 
Now the question is:
***How can I reliably position a slider above and with the same length of the x-axis?***

I have tried to bind properties concerning the width and position of the `Slider` and the `NumberAxis` in fxml and java. See minimal (not) working (as desired) example below:

**MainView.fxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.chart.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Slider?>

<VBox fx:id="timeBox" prefHeight="600" prefWidth="800" maxHeight="600" maxWidth="800"
    xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <children>
        <Slider fx:id="timeSlider" blockIncrement="30.0" max="360.0" />
        <HBox fx:id="scrollBox" fitwidth="${timeBox.width}" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
            <children>
                <ScrollPane fx:id="timeScrollPane" fitToHeight="true"
                fitToWidth="true" fitwidth="${scrollBox.width}" HBox.hgrow="SOMETIMES">
                    <content>
                        <LineChart fx:id="timeChart">
                            <xAxis>
                                <NumberAxis fx:id="timeAxis" minorTickCount="1"
                                minorTickLength="1.0" side="TOP" tickLabelGap="30.0"
                                tickLength="1.0" tickUnit="1.0" upperBound="360.0" />
                            </xAxis>
                            <yAxis>
                                <CategoryAxis fx:id="appearanceAxis" prefWidth="160.0"
                                side="LEFT" />
                            </yAxis>
                        </LineChart>
                    </content>
                </ScrollPane>
            </children>
        </HBox>
    </children>
</VBox>
```

**MainViewController**

```
public class MainViewController implements Initializable {

    @FXML private VBox timeBox;
    @FXML private HBox sliderBox;
    @FXML private Slider timeSlider;
    @FXML private HBox scrollBox;
    @FXML private ScrollPane timeScrollPane;
    @FXML private NumberAxis timeAxis;
    @FXML private CategoryAxis appearanceAxis;
    @FXML private LineChart<Number, String> timeChart;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

        // idea: set the same x value, but it does not change anything
        timeSlider.setLayoutX(timeAxis.getLayoutX());
        // idea: bind the width, but it stays longer
        timeSlider.prefWidthProperty().bind(timeAxis.widthProperty());
    }
}
```

**Main.java**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;


public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("MainView.fxml"));
            Parent root = loader.load();
            Scene scene = new Scene(root,800,600);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

I know, what I have tried so far is not really much, but I just don't have an idea how to fix that.
The chart is meant to show the start-to-stop time of a video file on the x-axis and annotations with their appearance intervals on the y-axis.
Thanks for reading this…

Comment: Your `Legend` appears to be on the left of the `Chart`. So the width of your `Chart` node is the legend's width + the chart's width. That means that your `Slider` width, when put into a 'VBox' with the 'Chart' node, equals the `Chart`'s node width.

Comment: I know… but in a VBox, the content does not necessarily fit the entire width, does it? The width should be decreasable somehow. If I switch the legend to `""`, there will still be the categories and their max length is not defined. Can't a `Slider` be positioned exactly above the x-axis fitting its width?

Comment: My guess is there is a way to do this. If no one attempts this before I get off, I will make an attempt if I don't forget.

Comment: Thanks, the entire approach is about changing the slider thumb to a (dashed) line and make reach down to the x-axis (tick label) to be able to slide along values… Other ideas I had were deriving from `Slider`and replacing the tick label by a `NumberAxis` or adding a `Slider` to something deriving from `NumberAxis`.

Comment: I have seen, a `Slider` may be skinned, maybe one could skin it like being on top of a chart, but using the x-axis as its tick label. I will have a closer look at that, I think…